# How do I trigger an update in a Callout to update it's position after it's content has been resized?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a Callout whose content is resized by certain user interactions. The skin has an animation and after that the Callout is no longer positioned correctly and needs to be repositioned.

Is there any way to invalidate the Callout after the Callout content has been resized?

Answer (score 0):

It was simpler than I thought. I added an event handler to the resize event on the Callout content and then in that event called the Callout method `updatePopUpPosition()` to update the Callout position, obviously.

At first I was looking for one event that I could listen for after the Callout had been resized but that would involve dispatching a custom event when there is an effect. Adding an event handler for `resize` triggers multiple times when the resize effect is running but the animation and positioning is flawless so I'm keeping it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Callout xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexMouseEvent;
            import mx.events.ResizeEvent;

            protected function editorBar_resizeHandler(event:ResizeEvent):void {
                updatePopUpPosition();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <controls:MyContent id="editBar" width="100%" resize="editBar_resizeHandler(event)" />
</s:Callout>
```